# Absolute value and sign of an elasticity

Tags: economics, absolute-value

In my microeconomics book, I read that when we have $1+\dfrac{1}{\eta}$ where $\eta$ is an elasticity coefficient, we can write $1-\dfrac{
1}{|\eta|}$ "to avoid ambiguities stemming from the negative sign of the elasticity".

What does this mean? Is it always legitimate to perform such a transformation?

Comment: It should be negative.

Comment: The reason for the care is that elasticity has been traditionally defined in two different ways, the way you are familiar with, and the negative of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the elasticity coefficient $\eta$ is negative, then $|\eta|=-\eta$. The ambiguity arises because some people may suppress the negative sign and write it as a positive number instead. In this case, using $1+\frac{1}{\eta}$ becomes ambiguous.

For example, if $\eta=-2$ but people write it as $\eta=2$, then $1+\frac{1}{\eta}$ can mean $1-\frac{1}{2}$ or $1+\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, such a calculation is not always allowed...I'm guessing it relates to the constant itself.